# MySQL query troubles

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this query here:

```
select distinct oawa_id, 'Team Impact' as Club, FirstName, LastName
from team_impacts ti
left join session_participants sp
    on (sp.member_id = ti.id)
    or (sp.member_id = ti.oawa_id)
order by LastName asc, FirstName asc
```

and this provides me with a list of users, but some users have the same first name and last name and some come with an `oawa_id` and some don't. For example:

This is record list:

1. Brad May has an `oawa_id`
2. Brad May doesnt have an `oawa_id`

it's okay if some people do not have an `oawa_id`, but for cases like these, if people have the same name, get the one with the `oawa_id` and ignore the one without. That only applies to people with the same name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your question? Where's your sample data?

Comment: Add your code here so we can see everything http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is restructure your query with a group by clause

```
select max(oawa_id) as oid, 'Team Impact' as Club, FirstName, LastName
                                    from team_impacts ti
                            left join session_participants sp
                                    on (sp.member_id = ti.id)
                                    or (sp.member_id = ti.oawa_id)
                            group by Club,FirstName, LastName
                            order by LastName asc, FirstName asc
```